# "sapply(name, "[", 2)", what's the "[" means?

Tags: r

```
name

[[1]]

[1] "John"  "Davis"

[[2]]

[1] "Angela"   "Williams"

[[3]]

[1] "Bullwinkle" "Moose"
```

The data is as above, I want to take last and first name from the list. The code is:

```
lastname <- sapply(name, "[", 2)
```

My question: what does the `[` mean?

Answer (score 1):

It is `?Extract`ion operator.  Here, it extracts the 2nd element of the `list`.

```
sapply(name, `[`, 2)
```

In the OP's post, the `list` elements are `vector`s.  So, it checks the 2nd element and extract that element and output as a `vector` (`sapply`)